# Should I chain GUI tests or start the applet anew every time?

Tags: java, swing, coding-style, gui-testing

In the open source project [JChemPaint](http://jchempaint.github.com/), for example, the GUI is tested (using the FEST framework) by collecting about a dozen individual tests each into a few Java files. The applet is started only once per file, and several independent tests are performed in a chain.

I would like to know if this is good practice. Of course, starting up each time would cost time. I can see however problems with side effects of previous actions and possible exceptions, but I'm no expert. So, is it good practice to put several tests into one applet start?

(I'm looking also for a collection of best practices for GUI testing but can't pose such a question, hints are welcome nevertheless.)

Comment: *"I can see however problems with side effects of previous actions and possible exceptions"*  Well, if doing that combination of things successfully is what you are testing for, it makes perfect sense.

Comment: so, it's all as good as the docs are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm troubled by the awkward division between these two [top-level containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html):

[`org.openscience.jchempaint.application.JChemPaint`](https://github.com/JChemPaint/jchempaint/blob/master/src/main/org/openscience/jchempaint/application/JChemPaint.java)
[`org.openscience.jchempaint.applet.JChemPaintAbstractApplet`](https://github.com/JChemPaint/jchempaint/blob/master/src/main/org/openscience/jchempaint/applet/JChemPaintAbstractApplet.java).

After cursory reading, I am reluctant to be critical; but re-factoring the contents might limit the amount of duplicate testing required. In this very simplified [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/subway), common initialization is confined to the `initContainer()` method. By comparison, `JChemPaint` is considerably more complex and offers a number of applet parameters, the correct transfer of which should be tested.

Such re-factoring may be on-going. The [`appletests`](https://github.com/JChemPaint/jchempaint/tree/master/applettests) appear to date from an earlier period of development, while the newer [`jchempaint.src.test`](https://github.com/JChemPaint/jchempaint/tree/master/src/test) artifacts appear to reflect a more recent, annotation-based testing architecture.

Comment: Thanks for your time diving into this. What I'm still unclear about is does one really need FEST for this? Most bugs I found are in the applet logic, not the GUI (Swing etc) itself; additionally, any change in the looks (e.g. moving a button action to the menu) of the GUI will break FEST testing, and I don't like procedures that create more work than they're worth.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. Ideally, a button would be tested in the context of it's enclosing container, not as a function of which top-level container is used. Conversely, an applet should only need to test that its parameters arrive intact.

Comment: I will try to use awt.Robot for testing, as I had just some issues with FEST under Linux.